# python facebook-sdk fan_count issue

Tags: python, facebook

I cannot figure out how to get fan_count from a page.
I always get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./facebook_api.py", line 37, in <module>
facebook_graph.get_object('somepublicpage')['fan_count']
KeyError: 'fan_count'
```

The object only contains id/name and I cannot figure out how to give more permissions in order to get the 'fan_count' data.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
import facebook
import urllib
import urlparse
import subprocess
import warnings


warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)


oauth_args = dict(client_id = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
              client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
              grant_type = 'client_credentials')
oauth_curl_cmd = ['curl',
              'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' +      urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)]
oauth_response = subprocess.Popen(oauth_curl_cmd,
                              stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

try:
    oauth_access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(str(oauth_response))['access_token'][0]
except KeyError:
    print('Unable to grab an access token!')
exit()

print oauth_access_token
facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
print facebook_graph.get_object(PROFILE_ID)['fan_count']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.4 of the Graph API, you have to specify the fields you want to get returned. This would be the correct API call:

`/{page-id}?fields=name,fan_count`

It is called "Declarative Fields".